# how to do ipmi for fencing, hardware specific requirement?

Tags: ipmi, modprobe, dmidecode

i'm a total noob about ipmi, fencing and ha, i want to create node with high availability. wanna fencing node with ipmi.

```
root@proxmox01:~# ipmitool sensor
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Get Device ID command failed
Unable to open SDR for reading
```

question 1, how to configure ipmi for fencing, do my pc not meet any requirement specific hardware? this is what i do to check

```
root@proxmox01:~# dmidecode -t 1 -t 2 -t 3
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Product Name: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        UUID: 03000200-0400-0500-0006-000700080009
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Family: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: ASRock
        Product Name: Z77 Extreme4
        Version:
        Serial Number:
        Asset Tag:
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board
                Board is replaceable
        Location In Chassis:
        Chassis Handle: 0x0003
        Type: Motherboard
        Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
        Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Type: Desktop
        Lock: Not Present
        Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        Boot-up State: Safe
        Power Supply State: Safe
        Thermal State: Safe
        Security Status: None
        OEM Information: 0x00000000
        Height: Unspecified
        Number Of Power Cords: 1
        Contained Elements: 0
        SKU Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
```

i just doing

```
#modprobe ipmi_devintf
#modprobe ipmi_si
```

but when i'm running ipmitool sensor, the error output still the same, could'n open device at /dev/ipmi0

thereis dmesg output
do my hardware not meet any requirement to do ipmi module?

```
root@proxmox01:~# dmesg |grep ipmi
ipmi message handler version 39.2
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified kcs state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified smic state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified smic state machine at i/o address 0xca9, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified bt state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified bt state machine at i/o address 0xe4, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
ipmi_si: Unable to find any System Interface(s)
ipmi device interface
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a system which actually *has* IPMI.

Your cheap desktop motherboard, like virtually all such motherboards, does not.

Comment: how to check the device actually have a ipmi module with the cli/terminal??

Comment: @arifkhumaidi Consult its specifications before you buy it.

Comment: @arifkhumaidi: You buy a *server* which has IPMI support. It's listed in the specs.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it'll end up being very highly-available.